# How to order collection by ActiveStorage attachment name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I need to order a collection by 2 attributes. One is a regular attribute, I'll call it `attr` and the other is the name of an ActiveStorage attachment. The problem is that because of how ActiveStorage defines the relationship I can't join its table to order by one of its attributes.

This is roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file

  scope :sorted, -> { joins(:file).order(attr: :asc, 'files.filename': :asc) }
end
```

I know that `files` isn't the name of the table, this is just an example. I've messed around ActiveStorage's table name and even tried defining a relationship manually with ActiveStorage::Attachment and ActiveStorage::Blob without success.

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To order the documents on the DB server, you can join through attachments to blobs:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  scope :ordered_by_filename, -> { joins(file_attachment: :blob).order("active_storage_blobs.filename ASC") }
end
```

Alternatively, denormalize for performance. Keep a copy of the filename in the documents table:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  before_save { self.filename ||= file.filename }
  scope :ordered_by_filename, -> { order(filename: :asc) }
end
```

Finally, consider sorting in the app wherever feasible. (Pagination is one case where it’s probably *not* feasible.) Where scalability is a concern, it’s generally easier to scale your app server pool horizontally than your DB:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
  delegate :filename, to: :file

  def self.ordered_by_filename
    # Use the with_attached_files scope to avoid N+1 queries.
    with_attached_files.sort_by(&:filename)
  end
end
```

Comment: Guarantee of Origin! Added a piece of knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the `with_attached_<attachment_name>` scope does not appear in ActiveStorage Rails Guides, and it does not come up when searched for in Rails API docs, so it's not clear where it comes from. One of Rails' magics, it's mentioned in ActiveStorage::Attached::Model: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model.html